# SSAS Cube: different calculation only for one company

Tags: ssas, olap-cube

Here's my problem: I have an SSAS cube for multiple production companies. Company data is part of the "machine" dimension:

```
[Machine].[Company code]
```

Then I have two measures:

```
[Measures].[OEE] and [Measures].[OEE for company X]
```

In this case, I have to use the second measure for company X and the first measure for all other companies.

Is there a way to make a single measure which would display one measure for company X and another measure for other companies?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 2):

Several scenarios are possible (based on sources, underlying logic etc.)

1. For physical measures based on columns. Create calculated column in Data Source View with T-SQL: `case when {company X} then {column for this company} else {columns for other companies} end`. Use it as a physical measure in cube.
2. For both physical and calculated measures. Hide existing measures, create new calculated measure with MDX: `IIF([Machine].[Company code].CurrentMember is [Machine].[Company code].&[X],[Measures].[OEE for company X],[Measures].[OEE])`.
3. If only [OEE] name is allowed for both. Rename existing [OEE], hide both, create new calculated measure as `[Measures].[OEE] as IIF([Machine].[Company code].CurrentMember is...` from #2 above.
4. Use SCOPE statement. `SCOPE([Machine].[Company code].&[X],[Measures].[OEE]);
   THIS=[Measures].[OEE for company X];
   END SCOPE;`
5. Use direct way: `([Machine].[Company code].&[X],[Measures].[OEE])=[Measures].[OEE for company X];`

Please use any of these or update your question with more details.